# Possible to run Zeppelin paragraphs without browser?

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I have a paragraph that runs on a schedule to check the last minute worth of data and it sends an alert to another server if not within spec.

Can this or any paragraph that is run on a schedule using a cron job within an Apache Zeppelin notebook be run externally or without using the browser?

Comment: rest api is your friend. https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.6.0/rest-api/rest-notebook.html

Comment: This was not on my radar since I had no idea how to use a REST API (and very little knowledge on what they are), but upon investigation, this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you.

Comment: I bet you will like REST API specially compare to Web Service due to it's simplicity.